# Tuxboot vs UNetbootin?

Tags: boot, clonezilla, unetbootin

[Tuxboot docs](http://tuxboot.org/):

> Tuxboot helps you to create a bootable Live USB drive for Clonezilla live, DRBL live, GParted live and Tux2live. It is **modified from UNetbootin** and runs on both MS Windows and GNU/Linux.

How is it modified? What's difference between UNetbootin and Tuxboot?

Also, why is [Tuxboot preferred](http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php#linux-setup) over UNetbootin for  Clonezilla?

Answer (score 2):

According to Jack Wallen who wrote the article "[Create a portable version of Clonezilla live with Tuxboot](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/create-a-portable-version-of-clonezilla-live-with-tuxboot/)" in 2012:

> The problem with UNetbootin is that it doesn't support Clonezilla, one
>   of the most popular open source, bare-metal recovery tools. If you
>   want a USB version of Clonezilla, you can either go through the
>   command line-based steps to get it installed (which is not for the
>   faint of heart), or you can use a UNetbootin spin-off that supports
>   Clonezilla called Tuxboot.

Comment: This does not answer most of the author's questions.  It specifically does not address what the differences are nor how was Tuxboot modified  It only answers their last question, the reason its preferred, when attempting to use Clonezilla on a USB storage device.